# Visual Code agregar opciones de preprocesador en compilación

Tags: c, vscode

Habitualmente utilizo  codeblocks para programar en C con  raspberry y PC

Ahora  he decidido utilizar VCode para programar a través de ssh y me encuentro con el siguiente problema

Mi código lo utilizo en varias plataformas, por lo que incluye #defines que se habilitan según la plataforma con la que compilo, PC Ubuntu o  ARM raspbian.

En codeblocks utilizo la ventana 'Project build options' para indicar el #define que debe estar activo según la plataforma con la que compilo. Ejemplo codeblocks

[image: Ejemplo con codeblocks]

Sin embargo en VCode no encuentro el modo para conseguir lo mismo.

He consultado por la web pero no doy con ello, no me queda claro en que archivo de configuración
he de insertar esta opción

Saludos

Comment: En la documentación hay un buen ejemplo, donde establece defines para cada plataforma https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference